# How to open connection with autobahn_ node.js

Tags: node.js, autobahn

Hello came across autobahn documentation i was not able to open a connection can any one help me out. I created a server which accepts "ws" but i am not able to fire any event inside connection.onopen!!

`enter code here`

```js
var WebSocketServer = require("ws").Server
var http = require("http")
var express = require("express")
var app = express()
var port = process.env.PORT || 8083
var fs = require('fs')
var socketio = require('socket.io')(http)
var request = require('request')
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString
var autobahn = require('autobahn')
//require('node-monkey').start(); 



require('./router/route')(app);
app.set('views',__dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

var server = http.createServer(app)
server.listen(port)


var connection = new autobahn.Connection({
   url: 'ws://127.0.0.1:8083/ws',
   realm: 'realm1'}
);





connection.onopen = function (session) {

   // 1) subscribe to a topic
   function onevent(args) {
      console.log("Event:", args[0]);
   }
   session.subscribe('com.myapp.hello', onevent);

   // 2) publish an event
   session.publish('com.myapp.hello', ['Hello, world!']);
};

connection.open();
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Comment: here added app.js  code can you let me know where am doing wrong!!

Comment: I have my server running on that port but when it will hit onopen

Comment: Here is a complete example using Node, Express, Autobahn and Crossbar.io https://github.com/crossbario/crossbarexamples/tree/master/expressjs

Comment: Hello @oberstet thanx for the article. Much need one.